# How reputable is D.T. Suzuki among modern Zen Buddhists?

Tags: zen

Over the past year I've been studying Zen, and eventually came across a compilation of the writing of D.T. Suzuki, an anthology of such.

Needless to say I was impressed and profoundly influenced by this anthology, but I wonder what the reputation of his work is among modern Zen Buddhists. Do they typically consider it an accurate depiction and representation of Zen? And if not, where would one come across an accurate representation?

Comment: I don't know who down-voted the question, but to anyone who down-votes, please include a comment explaining why.  This will allow the original poster to improve the quality of the question, and this benefits us all.

Comment: I agree. With R. Barzell. I consider solitary downvotes to be divisive speech. Please refrain from divisive downvoting. Comments suffice. Upvoting question.

Comment: good question: extraordinary scholarship, meticulous reasearch, accurate & brilliant, the finest writer of Zen materials in English. thank you  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He’s pretty phenomenal if you ask me.  I’d highly recommend most of his earlier writings.  People forget that he had some training as a monk under a fairly renowned master.

Just remember, however.  There’s only one authentic representation of Zen - that which *you* find on the cushion staring into mushin.